# Integrating spring config server with "legacy" tomcat

Tags: tomcat8, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application packaged as a war file to tomcat 8. I would also like to have the properties come from a config server. This config server can be a simple spring boot executable jar file, connected to git.

I can't see to find a way to tell the "classic" tomcat (non-spring-boot) to look for configuration in the external config server. There's no "bootstrap.yml" for tomcat that I'm aware of?

Any assistance would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried environment variables or java system properties?

Comment: Yes, tried modifying JAVA_OPTS to add settings from bootstrap.yml, didn't seem like it made any difference.

Comment: Hmm... Just noticed this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/715
I think the root cause might be that I am still using ContextLoaderListener in web.xml. Will remove it and report back.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my web.xml still used the legacy implementation of ContextLoaderListener. This is not needed if your war is packaged as a spring boot application. Actually, this is what caused the problems. When I removed it, it let the configuration be picked up by spring boot itself.

See response here from Dave Syer:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/715